# How to checkout merge request locally, and create new local branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

I have GitLab repository there and I need to test every merge request locally, before merging to the target branch.

How can I pull/fetch merge request as a new branch?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

1. Pull merge request to new branch

   `git fetch origin merge-requests/REQUESTID/head:BRANCHNAME`

   i.e 
   `git fetch origin merge-requests/10/head:file_upload`
2. Checkout to newly created branch

   `git checkout BRANCHNAME`

   i.e (`git checkout file_upload`)

OR with single command

`git fetch origin merge-requests/REQUESTID/head:BRANCHNAME && git checkout BRANCHNAME`

i.e 
`git fetch origin merge-requests/18/head:file_upload && git checkout file_upload`

Comment: To fetch updated changes from the pull request, simply do a git pull on the branch, `git pull origin merge-requests/10/head`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for closed Merge Requests

Answer (score 30):

This is also documented in GitLab online documentation :
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_troubleshooting.html#check-out-merge-requests-locally-through-the-head-ref

They supply this script (git alias) :

```
[alias]
    mr = !sh -c 'git fetch $1 merge-requests/$2/head:mr-$1-$2 && git checkout mr-$1-$2' -
```

Then you can use this command :

> git mr origin 4

So a new local branch `mr-origin-4` will be created.

Comment: That documentation is now located at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviewing_and_managing_merge_requests.html#checkout-merge-requests-locally-through-the-head-ref

Comment: How to get particular patch within this MR?

Comment: Thanks for this hint. It works. However, how to push back commits to this particular MR?

Comment: New documentation link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/reviews/#checkout-merge-requests-locally-through-the-head-ref

Answer (score 19):

You can also add the line

```
fetch = +refs/merge-requests/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/merge-requests/*
```

to your `.git/config` (section `[remote "origin"]` or replace `origin` with your remote's name) to have `git fetch` fetch all merge requests. This line is in *addition after* any already existing `fetch` line (the `+` causes this to be added, not replacing).

Comment: How to get particular patch within the MR?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar You mean `git cherrypick`? Otherwise please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: In gerrit i can fetch particular patch set with command like `git fetch ssh://user@gerrit.it.**.com:29418/OneSearch/controller/xx  refs/changes/30/1228430/3 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD` where `3` is the patch set pushed to the review 1228430. Is there any such option in gittlab MR?

Comment: So I dont want latest change/patch in the MR, instead a particular patch set after the review created. e.g. Say once MR is created if user has pushed multiple changes from the initial code. Each code change push will be a revision/patch right? in that i need to download locally a particular change/patch set to test.

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar I'm afraid I don't know, you'll have to ask a separate question instead, maybe someone else knows

Comment: /git/config has multiple sections. Which section should this line be added to? And in that section, there may already be a line that starts with "fetch =". What do do in that case?

Comment: @MikeNakis Edited for clarity

Answer (score 12):

There is a <kbd>Check out branch</kbd> button in GitLab.

[image]

Then you can copy comments from ***Step 1. Fetch and check out the branch for this merge request***.

```
git fetch <repo> <branch>
git checkout -b <branch>
```

[image]