# How do I test a pull requests locally before merging from a forked version of my repo when I have different pull requests from different users

Tags: git, pull-request, git-fork

Well, I am a bit new to git.

I am working on a project with my team members, I created a git repo that has my source code. A team member makes a fork of my repo, makes some addition and then submits a pull request to my master branch.

I want to test this code first before merging it into my master branch, he created a topical branch named "additional-changes" for the pull request and maybe deletes the branch after submitting the request.

so I go this way

```
git checkout -b test origin/master
```

but I get errors.

So do I need to add a remote for this team member's branch first before checking it out? I get errors like the branch does not exist.

Please ignore my long stories and just give me a step by step procedure to handle a situation like this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: please read my question again

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: It appears you can pull merge requests locally [Git: How to checkout merge request locally, and create new local branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44992512/git-how-to-checkout-merge-request-locally-and-create-new-local-branch)

Add his forked project as a remote:

```
git remote <name_other_than_origin> <url>
```

Then you would do the following:

```
git fetch <name_of_forked_remote>
git checkout additional-changes
```

See [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch) and [Checkout branch on different remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30862558/checkout-branch-on-different-remote).

Comment: Yes, it is actually on a remote branch, it is on a forked version of my remote repo

Comment: So what if I have many users sending in pull requests, do I add all of them as remote?

Comment: Actually there may be a simpler way to do this. Are you guys using a central git server (e.g. GitLab, Bitbucket, Github)?

Comment: bitbucket and it is a private repo

Comment: I updated the answer with a generic link to a stackoverflow question. Atlissian also have an [aritcle about how to view merge requests locally](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-locally-fetch-and-checkout-a-pull-request-724402529.html).